# Change inherited super method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I would like to change the super method of an inherited class. I have something like that:

```
class A {
    public void method() {
        // Do something here
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void method() {
         // Do something here
         ...
         super.method();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        if(useB()) {
            // Use B's method
            super.method();
        } else {
            // Use A's method
            super.super.method();
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can see, sometimes I need to use A's method and sometimes the B's one. Then, how should I do that?

Comment: I think the short answer would be: you shouldn't. You should think about your structure, and try to solve this without the a-->b-->c structure. Think about your design, and why this has occured. The fact that this 'problem' is here is called a 'code smell', and means something is probably off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a preservation method in your `B.java`

```
class A {

    public void method() {
        // Do something here
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public void preserveMethodA(){
         super.method();
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
         // Do something here
         ...
         preserveMethodA()
    }

}

class C extends B {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        if(useB()) {
            // Use B's method
            super.method();
        } else {
            // Use A's method
            super.preserveMethodA()
        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not right, but you can always add flag. if the flag is true then B method is called, and if it's false then A method is called.

```
class A {
    public void method(boolean flag) {
        // Do something here, ignore flag
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void method(boolean flag) {
         if (flag) {
             //do something
         } else {
             super.method();
         }
    }
}

class C extends B {
    @Override
    public void method(boolean flag) {
        super.method(useB());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition `if (useB())` outside of `C.method()` and upcast the instance of `C` to either `A` or `B` depending on the result of `useB()` and invoke `method()` on the upcasted instance.